# Dictionary with dictonary inside to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have dict with structure like this:

```
{'periodicity' : 'false',
 'load' : '45',
 'cell' : '33',
 'capacity' : '20'
 'SList' : [{'sPer' : '22',
   'sRep' : '43',
   'sMes' : 's5'},
  {'sPer' : '22',
   'sRep' : '43',
   'sMes' : 's6'},
  {'sPer' : '22',
   'sRep' : '43',
   'sMes' : 's7'}],
 ...}
```

And I made dataframe from that dict. The problem is that I got 3 rows with exactly the same value, except the SList column, you can see why, but I need just one dict which look like this:

```
periodicity     load      cell     capacity                                 SList
  false          45        33         20          {'sPer' : '22','sRep' : '43','sMes' : 's5'}, {'sPer' : '22', 'sRep' : '43', 'sMes' : 's6'}, ...
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either [`pd.DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) by specifying that the keys of the dictionary must be passed as the index labels with `orient="index"` and transpose it:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient="index").T
```

---

Or, let [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) do the parsing for you directly:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
json_normalize(d)
```

Both approaches yield:

[image]